# Bitbucket is not able to communite to jenkins through webhook

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I am not able to post the changed commits from bitbucket to jenkins ...

http://xx.xx.x.x:443/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke

Is this correct url to pull the changes to jenkins.. Please suggest any url that worked before..

Comment: Is that a public, non-RFC1918, IP? Is it accessible from the public Internet? Is Jenkins listening for a specific hostname, or on a specific port?

Comment: Its public IP address.. I am able to ping from different network..

Comment: It looks like you are mixing HTTP and HTTPS. You have http:// as the scheme, but are calling port 443, which is https. There isn't any magic to the scheme/port combinations. It's possible to serve http on port 443. However, some applications may assume https because of usage of port 443.

Comment: Thank you .. Its working